# Can't get Observable mapping from JSON to Object to work

Tags: json, angular, observable, angular2-services

I made an application in Angular2 beta 7 that retrieves movie information from a web API. This all worked fine, but now I'm trying to do the same thing in de final release of Angular 2. I can get most of the application to work, except for the mapping of the JSON information to my own MovieInformation object.

*movie-information.ts:*

```
export class MovieInformation {
    constructor(
        public imdbID: number,
        public title: string,
        public year: number,
        public genre: string,
        public runtime: string,
        public poster: string,
        public director: string,
        public writer: string,
        public actors: string,
        public plot: string,
        public metascore: number,
        public imdbRating: number,
        public imdbVotes: number,
        public type: string,
        public favorite: boolean = false
    )
    {

    }
}
```

*movie.service.ts*

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Movie} from '../model/movie';
import {MovieInformation} from "../model/movie-information";

const searchMoviesUrl = (title) => `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${title}`;
const movieInformationUrl = (imdbId) => `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}`;

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    constructor(private http:Http) {

    }

    ...

    getMovieInformation(movie:Movie): Observable<MovieInformation> {
        console.log(movieInformationUrl(movie.imdbID));
        return this.http.get(movieInformationUrl(movie.imdbID)).map(result => result.json())
        .map(m => new MovieInformation(m.imdbID, m.Title, m.Year, m.Genre, m.Runtime, m.Poster, m.Director,
                m.Writer, m.Actors, m.Plot, m.Metascore, m.imdbRating, m.imdbVotes, m.Type, movie.favorite))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is map the JSON result (http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1245526):

```
{"Title":"RED",
"Year":"2010",
"Rated":"PG-13",
"Released":"15 Oct 2010",
"Runtime":"111 min",
"Genre":"Action, Comedy, Crime",
"Director":"Robert Schwentke",
"Writer":"Jon Hoeber (screenplay), Erich Hoeber (screenplay), 
Warren Ellis (graphic novel), Cully Hamner (graphic novel)",
"Actors":"Bruce Willis, Mary-Louise Parker, Heidi von Palleske, Karl Urban",
"Plot":"When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, 
former black-ops agent Frank Moses reassembles his old team in a last 
ditch effort to survive and uncover his assailants.",
"Language":"English, Russian",
"Country":"USA",
"Awards":"Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins & 17 nominations.",
"Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
"Metascore":"60",
"imdbRating":"7.1",
"imdbVotes":"239,853",
"imdbID":"tt1245526",
"Type":"movie",
"Response":"True"}
```

To my own MovieInformation model class using *.map(m => new MovieInformation(...))*, but I can't get the TypeScript compiler to recognize my mapping variables from the JSON, like m.Title which exists in the JSON.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong that causes this problem?

Comment: If I try to resolve it like

return this.http.get(movieInformationUrl(movie.imdbID)).map(result => new MovieInformation(result.json().imdbID, result.json().Title...

then it works, but I find using result.json() all the time very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

```
return this.http.get(movieInformationUrl(movie.imdbID)).map(result => result.json())
            .map((m: any) => new MovieInformation(m.imdbID, m.Title, m.Year, m.Genre, m.Runtime, m.Poster, m.Director,
            m.Writer, m.Actors, m.Plot, m.Metascore, m.imdbRating, m.imdbVotes, m.Type, movie.favorite))
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Whereas the solution lies in the (m: any) defining m as being of any type so the compiler presumes any variable is available from any, like Title and Year in my example. So m: any is the JSON response that I get.

Without typing m as any, the compiler sometimes can't resolve the variables and can't start the application. With this solution this fixes my problem.